# Website shortcuts icons lost after a crash

Tags: browser, home-screen-shortcuts, nova-launcher

I am using Nova launcher and after a crash, all shortcuts to websites on my home screen lost their icons. Right now, all of them look the same: with the default green android icon. They still work - but icons are lost. I've tried restarting the launcher, restarting the OS - no difference. Any ideas how to restore / refresh them without recreating each one of them manually?

OS: Android 7.0

Browser: Google Chrome

Comment: Please specify which browser's shortcut you have created. Nova launcher have a backup and restore utility of launcher data. I think you haven't done that, so you need to create them again and backup them next time. If you were using SD card as internal storage and when SD card is removed, app that stores data to SD card are showing similar to green android icons.

Comment: It's Google Chrome. Thanks for the reply and workaround with backing up nova's settings. It would be nice to have a way of refreshing all icons at once though.

Comment: This links may help you: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36426/where-are-displayed-shortcuts-stored?rq=1

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54228/android-4-1-2-apps-shortcut-disapperead-from-home-screen